# How can i set a docker action with OpenWhisk in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I was testing OpenWhisk on Bluemix. What i want to do is very very simple. I have a js script that works (it's just a console.log). I have a Dockerfile making a docker .. when i run my docker i can see my console.log \o/ (i know it's amazing)

Then i create my action ......
I try to run it from Bluemix UI
I get this :

failed to invoke action XXX/XXXX: Container hash or name expected in `makeContainer`.

Just what does it means ? I couldn't find anything on it.

ps : If you know where i can find some real doc about how to use docker container for actions i would be very happy :).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit : In the end the problem was that i was trying to pull from a private docker repo. I have to say the error message is not explicit x). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation about creating docker actions here: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#openwhisk_actions_docker

Instructions helps you download the docker sdk for OpenWhisk, and allow you to create a docker action that you can invoke from CLI or Web UI.

If you create the action using the Web UI you need to specify the docker Image from Docker hub using the format `username/imagename` like `openwhisk/example`

If you need more help feel free to reach the team on Slack for more real time interactions and we should be able to help you and get your feedback on how can we improve the user experience.

Team: https://developer.ibm.com/open/slack-request

Channel: #openwhisk https://dwopen.slack.com/messages/openwhisk

Comment: Thanks, i edited my post. I was trying to pull from a private docker rep .. I switched it to public and it works. Thanks for the slack.

Comment: @Toruide is there is anything missing or blocking you from using the JavaScript actions instead of building a docker action. Any npm package missing? we are working on adding the ability to upload a zip that can contain your node_modules folder. Feel free to provide feedback you can use the github repo https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues

Comment: Hi, first i think uploading a zip file containing node_modules can be tricky :/. Some npm package are "built" when you npm install them so i'm not sure those would work well when zipped. 
Me i need to install some C lib and also phantomjs. I am pretty sure this is not possible (at least not easly) without docker.

Comment: You are correct to have more control over the dependencies, and the environment then docker action is the best solution.